# Sheet metal working. Making a flange

Tags: mechanical-engineering, autodesk-inventor

I've been working on a flat pattern design to send to the machine shop and have run into a problem making the support piece. The problem I've been hitting is I can't figure out how to flange off of the sides in a triangle shape to meet the top. The best way to explain this is through the attached screenshots.[image: Shot to show what the piece is supposed to look like... I used the face tool which I'm pretty sure is not the right to for the job.]

The triange support piece in between the bend is the problem child. I'm basically trying to make that piece but as a bend off of the side of the part. The reason I want to do this is so that the flat pattern will come out properly. If anyone can explain to me how to make this bend correctly or a better way of doing this it would be greatly appreciated. I'm going to attach one more screenshot of my attempt on the other side. [image: Attempt two]

This is my first post so if anyone has any pointers on what else to include in the post please let me know. To anyone that replies thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't make bends like this that completely fill up the corner where three pieces meet, because the bends have a finite sized radius. You can do it by folding thin paper, but not with sheet metal! You could undercut the corner of the triangle to leave a small "hole" in the corner of the finished joint. Or, use a separate piece of metal for the triangle, with two bends so it can be fixed to both sides of the main piece.

Comment: @alephzero I figured out the undercut like you said and it is leaving a small hole in the corner and also around the bends. I'm going to try the second option you explained.